# Using C++ dll on python

Tags: python

I have a project involving pedestrian simulation
I'm planning to use libpedsim.dll in python with Ctypes but so far I cannot make the functions working
Can anyone point out how to make use of this DLL?

This is the class documentation: http://pedsim.silmaril.org/documentation/libpedsim/latest/classPed_1_1Tscene.html
This is the link for the download: http://pedsim.silmaril.org/download/

I tried to call it this way but it said 'WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000'

```
from ctypes import *
pedsim = windll.libpedsim
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libpedsim.dll')
lib[6]()
getattr(pedsim, "??0Tscene@Ped@@QAE@ABV01@@Z")
```

Comment: It looks like you have name-mangling. Can you disable that? What are the requirements to import from a python DLL?

Comment: `??0Tscene@Ped@@QAE@ABV01@@Z` is `public: __thiscall Ped::Tscene::Tscene(class Ped::Tscene const &)`. You're probably not able to use ctypes to access C++ classes.

Comment: I'm sorry while I do have access to the source I have little understanding in C++. What I need to do is to perform http://pedsim.silmaril.org/documentation/libpedsim/ but in python. Is there any alternatives for me to use this dll?

Comment: While this is possible, you will need to have a very good understanding of the C++ ABI (which is undefined), and won't be able to use anything that requires a new template.  I highly suggest that, if you must use python, to consider writing a C wrapper for the C++ code so that you can at least have a simpler ABI to contend with. You should also consider Cython.

Comment: @hughdbrown you cannot disable mangling for C++ classes. Also mangling is not a problem by itself.

Comment: Okay, I just read up about cython a little bit but I have problem on using it o this. I have to use the source pedsim.h on python. While it is one of the alternatives, I really wish I could use it straight to the dll.